# What am I looking at when I run a dir command from the AWS command line from an EC2 master instance from an EMR cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

When I execute a dir command from the master instance in a EMR cluster, am I looking at the file structure for the master or HDFS folders located across the slave(s)? Where is /home/ssm-user located?

Answer (score 1):

If you run file system commands in the master instance, you are running the commands against the files managed by the OS of the master instance, not the files managed by HDFS.

Need to use hadoop command such as `hadoop ls` to access the HDFS files.

- [hadoop ls](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#ls)

Comment: Thank you for answer!  This was the help I needed.